Solana node laggin in sync
This is my configuration for the node:-
#!/bin/bash
export SOLANA_METRICS_CONFIG="host=https://metrics.solana.com:8086,db=mainnet-beta,u=mainnet-beta_write,p=password"
exec solana-validator 
--identity ~/validator-keypair.json 
--entrypoint entrypoint.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint2.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint3.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint4.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--entrypoint entrypoint5.mainnet-beta.solana.com:8001 
--expected-genesis-hash 5eykt4UsFv8P8NJdTREpY1vzqKqZKvdpKuc147dw2N9d 
--accounts /mt/accounts 
--account-index program-id 
--snapshots /mt/snapshots 
--ledger /mt/ledger 
--log ~/log/solana-validator.log 
--rpc-port 8899 
--dynamic-port-range 8000-8099 
--rpc-bind-address 0.0.0.0 
--limit-ledger-size 
--wal-recovery-mode skip_any_corrupted_record 
--known-validator PUmpKiNnSVAZ3w4KaFX6jKSjXUNHFShGkXbERo54xjb 
--known-validator Ninja1spj6n9t5hVYgF3PdnYz2PLnkt7rvaw3firmjs 
--known-validator ChorusmmK7i1AxXeiTtQgQZhQNiXYU84ULeaYF1EH15n 
--known-validator CakcnaRDHka2gXyfbEd2d3xsvkJkqsLw2akB3zsN1D2S 
--known-validator SerGoB2ZUyi9A1uBFTRpGxxaaMtrFwbwBpRytHefSWZ 
--known-validator FLVgaCPvSGFguumN9ao188izB4K4rxSWzkHneQMtkwQJ 
--known-validator qZMH9GWnnBkx7aM1h98iKSv2Lz5N78nwNSocAxDQrbP 
--known-validator GiYSnFRrXrmkJMC54A1j3K4xT6ZMfx1NSThEe5X2WpDe 
--known-validator LA1NEzryoih6CQW3gwQqJQffK2mKgnXcjSQZSRpM3wc 
--known-validator Certusm1sa411sMpV9FPqU5dXAYhmmhygvxJ23S6hJ24 
--known-validator 9bkyxgYxRrysC1ijd6iByp9idn112CnYTw243fdH2Uvr 
--known-validator 12ashmTiFStQ8RGUpi1BTCinJakVyDKWjRL6SWhnbxbT 
--known-validator FdaysQ2BZWUGBy8nqFgiudnrhzJp4xChQ8B4zJdc2JZB
Using the above configuration, we were able to sync the node for the first time, and it remained in sync for approximately 24 hours. However, after that, it began to lag in syncing, and the slot gap increased over time.
